# jQuery(#id).val() vs. getElementById(#id).value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I been searching but I can only find articles talking about one or the other. Which one is better?

I'm making a small web app where performance is not a big concern since there's nothing complex going on.

I considered using jQuery's `val()` function since maybe it solves some inconsistency I'm not aware of, but `getElementById.value` IS faster (although the end user won't notice.)

So which one should I use? Is jQuery's non-native method worth the lower performance to gain more compatibility?

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." --Donald Knuth

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The biggest advantage of using `jQuery().val()` over `document.getElementById().value` is that the former will **not** throw an error if no elements are matched, where-as the latter will. `document.getElementById()` returns `null` if no elements are matched, where-as `jQuery()` returns an empty jQuery object, which still supports all methods (but `val()` will return undefined).

There is **no** inconsistency when using `.value` for form elements. However, jQuery.val() standardises the interface for collecting the selected value in select boxes; where as in standard HTML you have to resort to using `.options[this.selectedIndex].value`.

Comment: Actually there is some inconsistency between browsers with line breaks in textarea `value`s that jQuery's `val()` normalizes, although I would rather it didn't.

Comment: @TimDown Do you have more info regarding the inconsistencies? On Chrome 53, Firefox 47 and Safari 9.1 on Mac OS X at least there aren't any. Tested with this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5hvy75Lf/

Comment: @Dennis98: HTML5 has sorted this issue out because it has standardized on just using the LF character for any line break in the value and I think all recent browsers comply. Certainly old IE, and possibly some old versions of Safari and/or Opera, used CR+LF rather than just LF.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 7):

If you're using `<select>` elements as well, `.value` won't work whereas `.val()` will.

I would not mind about performance of just getting a value. If you want the best performance, perhaps you shouldn't use a library at all.

Answer (score 3):

`jQuery` does so many nice little error handling things (look below) that I would never write a line of `javascript` without `jquery` in a browser again.

- First, `val` works on checkbox groups, selects, gets html, and the
  like.
- Second, `$` lets you use sizzle selectors, so in the future, you can
  easily switch between an `ID` and a `CSS` path.
- Third, your code will be so much easier to read and maintain if you
  just use `jQuery`, that the time you save maintaining your code
  outweighs any speedup that you admit your users won't see. Finally,
  `jQuery` is a very popular, very widely used library. They will make
  `$` and `val` as fast as they can.

Comment: just a small note: val() does **not** (unfortunately) work on checkboxes, at least not in any useful way. It returns the value that would be set if the checkbox was checked - but it doesn't take into account whether if it is checked or not. +1 for not writing a line of JS without jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I think using pure `Javascript` is quicker for the following reasons:

1. You won't have to learn more than pure `js`
2. If you don't want errors, use `catch(exeption)` (I think...)
3. You don't have to put in that little extra time to type in the code to initiate `jquery`
4. The browser responds quicker if you don't use `jquery`
5. Normal `js` works (in a better way) on checkboxes @johndodo

Thank you for listening to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into the performance differences with this recently and, slightly unsurprisingly, using vanilla JS to grab a value is faster than using jQuery. However, the fallbacks that jQuery provides to prevent errors, like what @Matt mentioned, is very useful. Therefore, I tend to opt for the best of both worlds.

```
var $this = $(this),
    $val = this.value || $this.val();
```

With that conditional statement, if `this.value` tries to throw an error, the code falls back to the jQuery `.val()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/checkbox/same-name-group.php is an implementation for checkboxes, apparently options just need to be named the same with the array brackets notation in the  name i.e.:  `name="sport[]"`  then yu get the array inJavascript  via: `var sports = document.forms['demoForm'].elements['sport[]']`

I was looking for a **selection** type field solution **without using jQuery** and I came across this solution:

The Selection group is an object: HTMLCollection, and it has a **lenght** method and a **selectedOptions** property, which allows you to iterate through its **label** properties to populate an **Array** with the selected options, which then you can use:

```
...
    vehicleCol = document.getElementById('vehiculo').selectedOptions;
    vehiculos  = [];

    if (vehicleCol !== undefined) {
        for (let i = 0; i < vehicleCol.length; i++) {
            vehiculos.push(vehicleCol[i].label.toLowerCase())
        }
    }
...
```

[image: Web app and Console]

Answer (score -3):

I'd use jQuery's val(). Shorter code means faster download time (in my opinion).

Comment: If you're using jQuery, yes. Otherwise I doubt the savings from `document.getElementById('test')` to `$('#test')` weigh up the 31KB of the library itself.

Comment: When we talk about using jQuery I assume the library is already loaded for other reasons, I don't anybody would load jQuery just to get field values.