# How do I append new anchor to options in drop down using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to create a new anchor tag dynamically along with option in drop down list?

I want  to open new page in new tab from drop down list box. Is there is any other way to do this?

So far, I have tried this:

```
function abc
{
    $("#reportimg").fadeOut("slow"); 
    <?php $link="<html><a Onclick='openreport($report2)'>Open</a></html>";?>
    var text="<?php echo $report2.$link;?>";  
    var val="<?php echo $report2;?>"; 
    alert(text);
    $('#report_list').append( new Option(text,val) );
}
```

Comment: You can not have a link inside of a select element. And what is with the `<html></html>` tags?

Comment: do you mean to have php tags in your javascript? They're evaluated server side (if at all) and won't be present on the client side where the javascript is processed.

Comment: why you don't associate data attribute with the destination url to each option and then use change event from jQuery and when a user choose an option it will redirect user to a new tab.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this structure (of course you can replace my stuff with your PHP generation, but there's no need to use `<a>` or whatever):

```
<select id="report_list">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

And this Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#report_list").on("change", function () {
        openreport($(this).val());
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/AyvUZ/2/

This listens for the `<select>`'s value to change, meaning an option was chosen. You can grab its value with `$(this).val()` (which is all you seemed to need in your example code), and pass that to `openreport`. This is all done without modifying the original HTML.

Comment: he has jQuery - what's with `window.onload` and `document... .onchange`?

Comment: @Alnitak What's wrong with a vanilla JS solution? I'm not gonna lie, I completely forgot they were using jQuery. It doesn't mean it **has** to be used. But obviously it's preferred, so I'll update my answer

Comment: mostly better, but FWIW `$(this).val()` is one of those things that is actually better written with vanilla JS - i.e. `this.value`

Comment: @Alnitak Yeah I don't think so. That's very contradictive of you. If you want jQuery to be used, use it. I haven't encountered a situation where `.val()` does something better (although `.val("value")` is a different story), but I'd rather stick with jQuery methods that take care of things we might not think of. I'm sure there's a reason why the `.val()` method in the jQuery source takes several lines of code

Comment: It's not just me saying that.  Remy Sharp and Adam Sontag both said the same at jQuery UK last week.

Comment: @Alnitak Hmm well that's interesting. To me, it's more conceivable inside of a handler, because you know `$(this)` will be something. Using `.val()` is nice when the selector may not return anything, and therefore the method will return `""` instead of failing with something like `document.getElementById("whatever").value` (which of course you should check for existence first). Also, I just saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322078/jqueryid-val-vs-getelementbyidid-value#comment-8835318 so that can be good or bad

Answer (score 2):

You can not actually force a browser to open a new tab, only a new window. Nowadays browsers do tend to open a new tab when you click on a "_blank" link or open a new window through JavaScript.

If you're OK with that (and I suspect, you're not since you asked specifically for a solution that opens a new tab), you can try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <select id="myDropDown">
        <option>Select a website</option>
        <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
        <option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
        <option value="http://www.msn.com">MSN</option>
    </select>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#myDropDown').change(function(el) {
                window.open($('#myDropDown').val());
            });
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps!