# Work around getElementById

Tags: javascript, performance, getelementbyid

I'm making an website game which uses many `document.getElementById` inside a `setInterval` that runs every 0.25 sec. This makes my webbsite slow after some time. I'm quite new to Javascript but I wonder if there's a more effective or efficient way to call and update a `HTML element` or create a effective loop that includes game latency and runs every 1 sec?

Comment: getElementById is the most efficient method to select an element there is, so if you're experiencing performace issues, the cause is more likely to be your own code than native implementations.

Comment: providing us a piece of your code, would be more helpful so find a solution to your problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322078/jqueryid-val-vs-getelementbyidid-value

Comment: JSPerf proves that `getElementById` is the faster than other methods http://jsperf.com/queryselectorall-vs-getelementbyid/6

Comment: If you do proper DOM sanitation i.e. attach and remove event listeners you dont need, remove elements you dont need from the tree, i'm sure you will come close to a good performance. I would run the code and watch the DOM structure/JS objects closely to see where it is killing performance.

Comment: Why are you looking up the element every time?

Comment: @epascarello -> cause he's new to javascript :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precache all `ID`'s.

Something in the lines of (pseudo code):

```
var all_objects = [];
...
onCreateObject = function(){
    all_objects.push(newObject.id)
}
```

and then just iterate through the `all_objects` variable.

As for the loop itself, there are solutions out there already: http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: Whow prechace ID's sounds really promising! And thanks for the link to the loop solution. I will now google on how to precache my ID's.

Answer (score 0):

set variables outside (above) your setInterval function:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("ID");
```

and then call them inside the setInterval function:

```
myDiv.something()
```