# How do I pass a parameter when submitting an form in javascript to a MVC controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a .cshtml page with several buttons like this:

```
<input id="btnViewHistory" type="submit" name="postFunction" value="View History" />
<input id="btnComments" type="submit" name="postFunction" value="Comments" />
```

When the form is submitted, the parameter "postFunction" is passed to the controller and I can check what button was pressed:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LabApprovals(ModelApproval model, int page, string postFunction)
    {
        if (postFunction == null)
        {
          ...
        }
        else if (postFunction == "View History")
        {
            ...
        }
        else if (postFunction == "Comments")
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

So if you click the "View History" button, when the controller is hit postFunction="View History".

I need to submit the form from Javascript for another reason other than a button press. I have the Javascript to submit the form, but how do I pass a parameter?I'm trying to get postFunction to have a value such as "Changed Page" when the controller is reached.

```
    $("#txtPage").kendoNumericTextBox({
    change: function () {
        $("#formLabApprovals").submit();
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Often one will put script-supplied values in a hidden field so they flow through to your controller but are invisible to the user.  Set the field's value in your existing script.

<input type="hidden" name="fieldFromScript" />

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.val(*value*)` method to assign the value attribute programmatically.

```
$("#txtPage").kendoNumericTextBox({
change: function () {
    $("#formLabApprovals").val("Changed Page");
    $("#formLabApprovals").submit();
} });
```

[jQuery(#id).val() VS getElementById(#id).value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322078/jqueryid-val-vs-getelementbyidid-value) is another article with some related information about using `.val()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to both the other answers, but I thought I'd post this as well.  It's what I finally did to get it to work. I found this page that was helpful: [jQuery - add additional parameters on submit (NOT ajax)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530635/jquery-add-additional-parameters-on-submit-not-ajax/2531379#comment62898894_2531379).

```
var input = $("<input>")
    .attr("type", "hidden")
    .attr("name", "postFunction").val("ChangePage");
$('#formLabApprovals').append($(input));
$("#formLabApprovals").submit();
```

Comment: I know it's an older post, but it still keeps on giving.  Thanks for the rewrite.