# jQuery .find() using parent id

Tags: jquery, find

I am trying to find the value of an input statement that does not have an id.

The html is:

```
<td id="LastName">
    <input type="text" value="Abner">
</td>
```

The jQuery code I am trying to use is:

```
var name = $('#LastName').find('input').value
```

But it keeps coming up empty.  I thought I had read about .find() properly, but apparently not.

Anyone see my error?

Comment: use `var name = $('#LastName').find('input').val()` , `value` is for getting the value from a DOM node using regular javascript `.val()` gets the value from a jQuery object, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322078/jqueryid-val-vs-getelementbyidid-value\

Comment: Dag nabit!  I knew that.  One of those forest for the trees goofs.

Answer (score 0):

As DelightedD0D commented, `.val()` is the correct way to retrieve a value from a text input.

Here's a working snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/tuywqucb/3/

One other thing to look out for.. if the `td` isn't correctly wrapped in a `tr` and a `table` tag, many browsers will omit it from the DOM which will make your element and thus your id disappear and thus not be found by jQuery.

Comment: Questions like this dont really need an answer. It should really be deleted by the asker or voted to close as *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."*  Additionally, I would posit that the OP left out the `tr` and `table` tags on purpose here because they were not relevant to the question ;)